# How to view Team Foundation Server in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, tfs, team-explorer

I installed MS Sql Server data tools 2013 and by installing that Visual Studio 2013 installed. After that I installed Visual Studio 2015 , I can see Team Menu in VS 2015 and can to connect to TFS, but I can't see the Team Menu in Visual Studio 2013.

I think TFS 2015 isn't incompatible with VS 2013.

How Can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 5):

You'll need to ensure the "Team Explorer" feature is installed. [You can download it separately if you need](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40776). SSDT installs only the Visual Studio Shell, which is a very, very barebones part of Visual Studio, the Shell doesn't include Team Explorer, but once installed, it integrates into that Shell instance just fine.

Then make sure you apply [Visual Studio 2013 update 5.](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48129) That way you have the latest TFS and Visual Studio Team Services compatibility fixes installed ofr that version of Visual Studio.

See also:

- https://jessehouwing.net/vsts-tfs-connect-any-visual-studio-version/

Answer (score 2):

**Visual Studio 2013 is not installed as part of SQL Server Data Tools 2013**. But it installs parts of Visual Studio that is used for the SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) called something like the integrated shell. This does not include the Team Explorer.

So as @jessehouwing has already suggested you need to install either a version of Visual Studio that includes Team Explorer or 'just' the [VS 2013 Team Explorer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40776).

Comment: @jessehouwing: your are completely right! I was so focused on explaining that I forgot the actual answer. I have now added this and I can see that you have also included the missing explanation to your answer.